# Discord.js bot command that creates new channel that certain roles can see

Tags: bots, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command called !apply that creates an a new channel that only people with a certain role can see and that person who does the command. If anyone could help with the code for that, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)?

Answer (score -1):

Use the [docs](https://discord.js.org) to make your own command no one will spoonfeed for you but as of the concept make a command that first create a channel then make a .then function that have the channel as the function and create a role and then overwrite the channel permissions to be allowed for that role and disallow for the guild ID which is the everyone role